# Google sheets compare times

Tags: google-sheets

In a spreadsheet I want to compare a time with now()

I want with a conditional format cell colors red when the time is due

But i noticed there is no way google sheets let me compare with a condition a given time with now. (See example in the link where I use 3 give times)

What is the proper way to compare a time with now()

A1 = 10:15

A2 = 10:20

now() => 10:10

```
if (now()>A1;TRUE;FALSE)
   **output TRUE,   expected value FALSE   
if (now()>A2;TRUE;FALSE)
   **output TRUE,   expected value TRUE
```

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yjuwPAkHFXVM3Th-va50YEgclO6XJzja1oKYM040yhQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now() has a date element it is today.  While the times do not.  So it will always be greater.

You need to remove the date which is a whole number.  One method is:

```
=MOD(NOW();1)
```

So your formula will be:

```
=IF(MOD(NOW();1)>A1;TRUE;FALSE)
```

[image]

One note: if all you want is True/False then you do not need the IF():

```
=MOD(NOW();1)>A1
```

Which will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` on its own.

Comment: this one works great, but I have a follow up quistion, I used =MID(...)  to extract the time part. This didn't worked. Do you know why MID() won't work to extract the time part from NOW()?

Comment: @Richard If this worked please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer. The reason mid did not work is mid works on strings.  Date/Time is saved as a number not a string.  Dates are whole numbers starting at 1/1/1900 and increasing 1 for every day since and time is a decimal based on 24 hrs being 1.  So it might show 9/2/2016 12:00 but it is stored as 42615.5.  so mid would parse that number not the date/time mask.